# Pandas Time difference of each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

| ID | STEP 1 | STEP 2 | ... | STEP 40 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-08 09:23:35 | 2022-03-08 10:23:35 | ... | 2022-03-19 09:23:35 |
| 2 | 2022-03-08 09:23:35 | 2022-03-08 11:23:35 | ... | 2022-03-18 09:23:35 |

I want to turn it into this:

| ID | Time 1-2 | Time 1-3 | ... | Time 39-40 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 296 days 08:08:05 | 297 days 08:08:05 | ... | 297 days 08:08:05 |
| 2 | 296 days 08:08:05 | 297 days 08:08:05 | ... | 297 days 08:08:05 |

I created a new dataframe:

```
index=[]
for item1 in range (1,40):
    for item2 in range (1,40):
        if item1  < item2:
            index.append("Time from Step "+ str(item1)+" to step "+ str(item2))

df = pd.DataFrame(-1, index=np.arange(len(caseList)), columns=index)
```

But I don´t know how to fill in the times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vectorial code.

If you don't have datetime type, uncomment the second step:

```
out = (
 df.set_index('ID')
   #.apply(lambda c: pd.to_datetime(c))
   .diff(axis=1).iloc[:, 1:]
   .set_axis([f'Time {i+1}-{i+2}' for i in range(len(df.columns)-2)], axis=1)
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   ID        Time 1-2         Time 2-3
0   1 0 days 01:00:00 10 days 23:00:00
1   2 0 days 02:00:00  9 days 22:00:00
```

*NB. I used "STEP 40" as "STEP 3" for the example here*

Comment: Thank you! It returns the labels: "1-2", "2-3"..."38-39". Do you know how I can get the values for: "1-2", "1-3", "1-4"..."1-39", "2-3","2-4",... "38-39"?

Comment: @justiww I don't understand the question, the labels are the column names, the values are in the dataframe's cells